# How to disable warning "No break at the end of case" in Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-luna, suppress-warnings

I'm using Eclipse (Luna SR 2) to write a C++ application.  How do I disable the "No break at the end of case" compile warning, ideally for a specific section of code?  It's annoying because our coding standard requires zero warnings and I want my cases to fall through, so I don't have to needlessly duplicate code.  Is there a way to do this with pragmas?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935935/how-do-i-turn-off-a-static-code-analysis-warning-on-a-line-by-line-warning-in-cd) is for code analysis so I am not sure if it is a dupe but it is worth a try.

Comment: That depends on the compiler you're using, not on the IDE. What do you compile the code with?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935935/how-do-i-turn-off-a-static-code-analysis-warning-on-a-line-by-line-warning-in-cd this could be your Solution

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Typing `//no break` should work just fine.

If you want to change that, you can try going to: Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Code Analysis
Then choose `No break at the end of case` and edit `//no break` to what you want.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935935/how-do-i-turn-off-a-static-code-analysis-warning-on-a-line-by-line-warning-in-cd) StackOverflow question, that should answer your question.

Hope you found this useful,

Alex

Comment: In my case (`Atollic TrueSTUDIO for ARM`) even after inserting the `// no break` (I also tried `/* no break */`) the warning was stuck until I cut the whole `case` block and pasted it back.

Comment: @nurchi, this solved my problem for TI Code Composer Studio v10.3.0. It also works if I use the syntax `// fall through`. Thanks.

Comment: `// Fall-through` (common for Java) or `// fall through` didn't work in my Eclipse, but `// No break` works (formatted it a little nicer)